# Non super admin cannot delete zoo visitor member

Tags: zoo-visitor, super-admin

what permissions do I need to give editors to allow them to be able to delete zoo visitor members? They can edit them fine but when they click on 'delete' when on the edit page of a zoo visitor member they get 'Error: you are not authorized to access this page'. Is it just super admins that can delete zoo visitor members?

Answer (score 1):

I've just released I need to give them permissions to the EE 'member' area of the site. They can delete zoo visitor members now.